# Is there a distcc-like tool for GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, distcc

Are there any tools like distcc for GHC?  Or other more primitive tricks for doing distributed compilation?

I realize GHC is extremely version sensitive.  Is this impractical since [GHC doesn't yet support cross-compilation](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/CrossCompilation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past I've configured distcc to invoke GHC as its compiler -- that works nicely in heterogeneous cluster environments (over ssh). I'm not aware of any other mechanism.

Comment: I'll play with distcc then, thanks.  I'd assume one needs ghc versions with compatible `.hi` files, but maybe they don't change quite as quickly as advertised.

Comment: You should try to have the same GHC on all machines. .hi files are somewhat portable, but I wouldn't guarantee it.

Comment: I know this is old, but it would be great if you could ellaborate a bit. A short demo/guide would be helpful.